# Common Lisp Implementations with Concurrent Garbage Collectors

Tags: concurrency, garbage-collection, common-lisp

What Common Lisp implementations, if any, provide a concurrent garbage collector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None.

If you run ABCL on top of a JVM then you might be able to use the concurrent GC of that JVM (if available). Though I'm not sure how well ABCL runs concurrently.